# i didnot find my bootstra. min.css file in my dist folder?

Tags: bootstrap.min.css

i download bootstrap 4 version for web development but in node_modules>bootstrap>dist>CSS> bootstrap.min.CSS is not there and in the online trainer link this file with html so what file i select to linked

Answer (score 0):

I'am afraid you may have downloaded the wrong one. Have you downloaded from the official bootstrap site:

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/download/

You will find the file in the folder css > bootstrap.min.css

You can copy that and put it in the project you are working on.

Comment: from this website i still not get this file.

Comment: one thing i observed that before extraction the file exits but after extraction there is no file?